# How to convert audio cdr files to something playable on a mobile phone, like mp3?

Tags: cd-ripping

I have a CD. Using Brasero I managed to get a cd.toc.bin file.

Then using https://smithdbr.wordpress.com/tag/cuebin/ I managed to get these files:

```
$ ls cd*
cd01.cdr  cd04.cdr  cd07.cdr  cd10.cdr  cd13.cdr  cd16.cdr  cd19.cdr  cd22.cdr  cd.toc.bin
cd02.cdr  cd05.cdr  cd08.cdr  cd11.cdr  cd14.cdr  cd17.cdr  cd20.cdr  cd.cue
cd03.cdr  cd06.cdr  cd09.cdr  cd12.cdr  cd15.cdr  cd18.cdr  cd21.cdr  cd.toc
```

Now for the love of God I do not understand what to do next with these cdr files. Some advise using poweriso, but it does not work on my machine. Some advise to use bin2iso, but I do not even want iso.

All I need is convert these files to something playable on a mobile phone, like mp3, for example.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: It's much easier to use a CD ripping software and do it directly from the audio CD. Sound Juicer, Asunder, etc. etc. Just search for CD rip in your Ubuntu Software app.

Comment: I am using Linux Mint, actually. But I guess the same software should work too. Can you provide a formal answer, so that I could credit you?

Comment: Yes, the same software. Unfortunately, if you're using Mint, this site isn't for you. Mint is not an official derivative and your question is likely to be closed. For other distros there's [unix.se].